# Is it possible to filter model's subfield in Strapi's GraphQL?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, strapi

With strapi GraphQL it is possible to limit the number of returned entries. However, is it also possible to limit the number of returned subentries? For example, if I have "galleries" content type with a field called "images", can I limit the number of Images returned?

This is what I tried and works:

```
query mainQuery {
  galleries(limit: 1) {
    name
    image {
      url
      id
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what I would actually like to do but does not work. There is no error or anything but the query returns all results, not just 1:

```
query mainQuery {
  galleries {
    name
    image(limit: 1) {
      url
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to fetch all galleries but only one image in each of them. Can anybody help me solve this?

Comment: Hello! Look have an issue, can you create one on GitHub please.